# how to get day month and year of any post from WP post object?Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get day month and year of a post from WP post object.

what I did is:

```
<?php
 $cpost=get_post($_GET['p_id']);
 echo $cpost->post_date;echo "<br>";
?>
```

Outputs:

```
2013-12-26 13:25:18
```

what I need is, day month and year as:

```
26 Dec 2013
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
echo date("d M Y", strtotime($cpost->post_date));
```

Here is the full parameter of the date function in PHP: [date function Parameters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Answer (score 4):

You can use something of the sort:

`<?php the_time('j F Y'); ?>` that will show the day, month and year of when the current post was posted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Always use strtotime function to get Date, Month, and Year etc.

```
echo date("d M Y", strtotime($cpost->post_date));
```

Use the options you want in date function && pass values in strtotime function.

-
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The format for the date is taken from the WordPress Settings (Settings > General).

```
<?php the_date('j F Y'); ?>
```

Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time